# WINDOWSFORMAPPLICATIONBASE.RUN(STRING ()) Taking too much cpu usage

Tags: c#, performance

Hello all  i have a rather simple question , i have a multi threaded application which is used to perform some periodic network updates 
i have a form say mainForm and one CustomuserControl to show network updates now on our mainForm we have a button and on this button click we can add as many CustomUSerControls as we want but it is consuming too much memory and cpu usage and when i go through performance analyzer the one which is included in visual studio it shows me that

```
MICROSOFT.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(string())
```

this method is taking almost 70-80 of cpu usage i don't know for what it is taking too much memory can any one explain it please

Answer (score 1):

You have a loop in your UI code that is constantly doing something and is using the CPU up.

Check for any polling you are doing and either put pauses in the polling or change it to a event based system that only processes information when your class receives a signal that there is information available to process.

If you are already listening to a event but the event is being fired very frequently you may need to find a way to decrease the number of events being fired or only process the event handler after enough time has passed.

Unfortunately I can not get any more specific than this without seeing the exact code that is causing the slowness in your code. I recommend using a code profiler to find which lines of your code (the line you showed us is .NET framework code, not much you can do with that) are being called the most and figuring out how to optimize them.

Comment: ok thank you for your time and valuable answer , i have to check for network updates continuously  and i can not wait for signal because of some requirements and also you are right i have a delegate which is setting some text properties and saving some info, so the point is that problem is somewhere else not in above mention method

Answer (score 1):

First you can try to use 
     var p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(...)

(You can wait for process termination using p)

The code behind is simpler and faster than the method you descibe.

Another option, if your automatically started network application is also a .NET application and you have its source:

1) split the network application in two parts: The loader (the .exe file) and move the network update method in a .dll file (adding a Library project to your solution and moving update method used source files to this new Library project).

2) add a reference to the Library project in both the network application loader and Form application.

3) from the Form application : do not start the network application loader, but directly call the network update method in the Library project.

With this second method, the form application have only to load a dll (much more fast than starting a new application each time a network update is required).